# Show error message in textfield in Yii

Tags: php, jquery, css, validation, yii

I have used  'enableClientValidation'=>true, in Yii active form to enable client side validation.It works fine but I want to display error message in the instead of under the field.
I worked according to [Yii. How to add css "error" class to input on form submit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11883820/yii-how-to-add-css-error-class-to-input-on-form-submit.This) code adds the error_input class on textfield but error still appears under textfield. 
Any Help Should be Appreciated.

My code is

```
<?php 
     $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
      'id'=>'contact-form',
      'enableClientValidation'=>true,
      'clientOptions'=>array(
          'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
          'afterValidate' => 'js:function(form, data, hasError) { 
              if(hasError) {
                  for(var i in data) $("#"+i).addClass("error_input");
                  return false;
              }
              else {
                  form.children().removeClass("error_input");
                  return true;
              }
          }',
          'afterValidateAttribute' => 'js:function(form, attribute, data, hasError) {
              if(hasError) 
                 $("#"+attribute.id).addClass("error_input");
              else 
                 $("#"+attribute.id).removeClass("error_input"); 
          }'
            ),

    )); ?>


    <div class="margin-bottom3 label-width1"> <?php echo $form->labelEx($Customer,'restaurant_name',array('class'=>'label-texts')); ?></div>
    <div class="name-common-div"> <?php echo $form->textField($Customer,'restaurant_name',array('class'=>'text-background customer_fields')) ?>
    <?php 
          echo $this->msg; 
          echo $form->error($Customer,'restaurant_name',array('class'=>'check-add-member-error')); 
    ?>
 </div>
```

How can i do this?`

Comment: it's more css problem. Personally i made wrapper for textfield+error. Float left them and give width. Then just add error for wrapper (if you wanna highlight textfield+error with red) or add error to errormsg class.

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna look at bootstrap extension for yii (http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/bootstrap/‎). It allows us to use a placeholder to do what you want, so it should be easier rather than creating your own css.